# WP_Query -- how to query for post ids or tag slugs

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-shortcode, wordpress-plugin-creation

I'd like to create a WP query that allows me to look for posts with particular tag slugs or pages with particular ids.

Here's what I've come up with:

```
$query = new WP_Query([
  'post_type' => array('any'),
  'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
  'tag_slug__in' => $tags_as_array,
  'post__in' => $post_ids_as_array
]);
```

But this doesn't work. It appears to work only when I remove the "tag_slug__in" key or the "post__in" key.

Is there a way to do this using WP_Query? I was hoping to not have to create a custom SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

**tag_slug__in**
only works for a blog post, not for custom post types or others. There is a reason that your query is not working correctly.

You need the **tax** query for custom post types or others.
Please follow this:
[The WordPress Query class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters)

```
$query = new WP_Query( [
        'post_type'      => [ 'any' ],
        'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
        'post__in'       => $post_ids_as_array,
        'tax_query'      => [
            [
                'taxonomy' => 'your-taxonomy-name',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms'    => $tags_as_array,
                'operator' => 'IN'
            ],
        ]
    ] );
```